# Ansible passing ssh username and Password using command line is not working

Tags: linux, ssh, ansible, devops

I need to pass username and password instead of using passwordless ssh keys.

I used below command for that

```
    ansible-playbook -i hosts.ini main.yml --extra-vars "ansible_sudo_pass=$(ansible_password) ansible_user=$(ansible_user) ansible_ssh_pass=$(ansible_password)"
```

my inventory file hosts.ini

```
    [all]
    10.1.5.4

    [defaults]
    host_key_checking = false

    [all:vars]
    ansible_connection=ssh
    timeout=20
```

Below is the error:

```
 TASK [add_repo : Add repository] ***********************************************
 fatal: [10.1.5.4]: FAILED! => {"msg": "Using a SSH password instead of a key is not possible because Host Key checking is enabled and sshpass does not support this.  Please add this host's fingerprint to your known_hosts file to manage this host."}
```

Note I tried:

1. Removing in hosts.ini file

```
    [defaults]
    host_key_checking = false
```

2. I also tried by changing `ansible_ssh_pass=$(ansible_password)` to `ansible_password=$(ansible_password)`

Comment: you should add 
`[defaults] 
host_key_checking = false
` into `ansible.cfg` file it should work

Comment: can you show me the contents of ansible.cfg file? and i tried the same command which you added above works fine for me

Answer (score 0):

Just posting answer for my question, it may help others in case they stuck with same issue.

I have added below entry in file /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg and it start working.

```
 host_key_checking = False
```

Even I have added same above settings in hosts.ini file, seems it does not taken effect.

Comment: thats what i added in the comment ;)

Comment: Sorry, I did not see your commet.  Thanks for your efforts and commet and yes, you pointed correctly in your commet

Comment: good... thanka...